# Object is not displaying values in my component html in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When am giving direct object to my angular component html it is displaying data but when I pass the data from server, I'm able to preview in console.log but unable to display in HTML.
.html

```
 <div class="profile-ud-list" *ngIf="event_details">  
                        {{event_details}}
     <div class="profile-ud-item">
         <span class="profile-ud-value">{{event_details.name}}</span>
     </div>
 </div>
```

.ts file:

```
event_details! : any;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEventData();
  }
  getEventData(){
    this.auth.iseventData.subscribe((eventData :any) => {
      console.log(eventData)
      console.log("type of operator: ",typeof eventData);  
           this.event_details = eventData;  
  });
}
```

console.log

```
{name: "ABC", category: "FAMILY", description: "desc", class: "11", …}

type of operator: object
```

Is there any way to pass the value from .ts to .html?

Comment: can you please try with async pipe like {{event_details | async}} in your html file?

Comment: i tried with async pipe like {{event_details | async}} in my html file but failed to obtain the desired result

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the `Subject` and add `async` pipe to your html.

html:

```html
<div class="profile-ud-list" *ngIf="event_details$$ | async as details">  
   {{details}}
   <div class="profile-ud-item">
     <span class="profile-ud-value">{{details.name}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

your .ts file will look like:

```js
event_details$$ = new Subject();

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEventData();
  }
  getEventData(){
    this.auth.iseventData.subscribe((eventData :any) => {
      console.log(eventData)
      console.log("type of operator: ",typeof eventData);  
      this.event_details$$.next(eventData);
  });
}
```

Don't forget to import the `Subject` from RxJs library.